# Using mogenerator with Core Data entities results in error saving the data store

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord, mogenerator, ftasync

I have an iPad app that I use MagicalRecord to save the Core Data entities in a SQLite d/b.  *Everything was working fine until I decided to use FTASync to sync the Core Data with Parse.com.*

Part of the requirements of FTASync are that you have to use mogenerator to generate the entity class files.  Now, I'm getting this error:

```
2013-12-14 12:38:59.375 foo[5451:70b] Failed to save to data store: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)
2013-12-14 12:38:59.380 foo[5451:70b]   DetailedError: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)";
    NSValidationErrorKey = objectId;
    NSValidationErrorObject = "<PreferenceData: 0x1149c3a0> (entity: PreferenceData; id: 0x114a7eb0 <x-coredata://03C39CC9-AC6C-4E56-BB5A-67038ACB6801/PreferenceData/p25> ; data: {\n    aAddlSvcs1 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs10 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs11 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs12 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs2 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs3 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs4 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs5 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs6 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs7 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs8 = \"\";\n    aAddlSvcs9 = \"\";\n    aApptInterval = \"\";\n    aDeleteOldAppts = \"-1\";\n    aDoubleBooking = \"-1\";\n    aHideHelpBtns = 0;\n    aHourFormat12 = 0;\n    aShopCloses = 1200;\n    aShopOpens = 1000;\n    createdHere = 1;\n    deleted = 0;\n    objectId = nil;\n    syncStatus = 2;\n    updatedAt = nil;\n})";
}
```

If I want to sync my Core Data store using FTASync, I **have** to use mogenerator.

So, what exactly is this telling me, other than "it couldn't be completed"?  How do I fix this?

**UPDATED:**
This is an image from the XCode Data Model Inspector

[image]

Comment: Just a thought, but this might be because you have `objectId` defined as an attribute on the entity when `NSManagedObject` itself has an `-objectID` method defined?

Comment: Another thought: `NSValidationErrorKey = objectId` sounds as if that property does not satisfy some constraint defined in the Core Data model. For example, if the attribute is not *optional*, `objectId = nil` would not be valid value.

Comment: **UPDATED**

The *objectID* is in the code generated by mogenerator!  As I indicated, I can't use FTASync unless I use mogenerator.  Any ideas around this?

Comment: @spokane-dude: Your error message contains `NSValidationErrorKey = objectId` (with a lower-case "d"). Where does that come from?

Comment: @MartinR from the **mogenerator** generated _Preferences.m file:  - 
    (PreferenceDataID*)objectID {
 return (PreferenceDataID*)[super objectID];
    }

Comment: @spokane-dude: But that is `objectID` (with upper-case "D"). The error message is about `objectId` (with lower-case "d").

Comment: Uhh-oh... let me look into that...

Comment: @MartinR  It's all coming from FTASync code... used all over the place!  My suspicion is that it takes over the MagicalRecord stuff for all of the Core Data entities... The version of FTASync os over 2 years old; I tried contacting the author two times via email and once by leaving an issue on GitHub... NOTHING!  very disappointing that he didn't even acknowledge the emails at least!  I have a question in the Parse.com forun asking for help, since they forked the FTASync code and made changes to it.  (long winded huh?) :D

Comment: @MartinR  Please re-write your comment above as an answer so I can close this out.  I'm giving up on FTASync and going with Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on syncing with Parse.com. [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1).  Thanks for your persistence, I appreciate it.

Comment: @spokane-dude: There is already an answer stating that this must be a validation error, there is no need to repeat it. - Unfortunately I have no experience with FTASync or parse.com, so I cannot comment on the advantages or disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined some validation rules in the xcdatamodel with the model editor: minimum/maximum values, required relationship, min/max string length.

When you insert objects via a GUI, you'll see immediate feedback when you try to create an object that fails validation. But if you create or modify an object in code, you won't see an error unless you try to save the Managed Object Context.

You can invoke -validateForUpdate: (or -validateForInsert: or -validateForDelete:) within the code that's creating your PreferenceData instance. Invoke it multiple times as you build the object, and you'll see where you're going wrong.